# SonarQube 6.5 web api logout not behaving as expected?

Tags: web-services, curl, sonarqube

We are trying to use sonarqube webapi and as part of prototyping I was testing the authentication apis using cURL .

**The session is not getting deactivated after calling logout** , and when I call a service again with a logged out cookie, it is getting authorized successfully.

Following are the steps I followed

1. **Login**

   > curl -v -c cookies.txt POST -d "login=admin&password=admin" http://sonar:9919/api/authentication/login
2. **Do a user token search** (which needs authorization) with the cookie

   > curl -b cookies.txt http://sonar:9919/api/user_tokens/search

   This is successfull and returns

   > {"login":"admin","userTokens":[{"name":"arunvg","createdAt":"2017-10-11T15:03:18+0400"}]}
3. **Logout**

   > curl -v -b cookies.txt POST http://sonar:9919/api/authentication/logout
4. **Repeat Step 2**, was expecting an error message like

   > {"errors":[{"msg":"Authentication is required"}]}

   but the call got successful and with same result in Step 2

Am I missing something here ? Any hints ?

Comment: Did you enable SSO (see sonarqube configuration)?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried enabling it. i.e setting sonar.web.sso.enable=true and restarting the server. But it is giving the same behavior.

Comment: We do not think this setting should be on in this situation. We also are facing the same problems understanding this API.

Comment: Thanks for the response, would update hear, when I find something fruitful.